# reading an INI file and retrieving the required information

Tags: delphi

I am looking for a way to read an `.ini` file to get the server host information from it. I got it loading static data, that part was easy, but I want to expand it so I can add more then one server in the `.ini`, and then let my program add them in order.

```
[Data]
Server[1]=tcp/80.7.229.47/7799 // server one
Server[2]=udp/80.7.229.47/7780 // server two
Server[3]=tcp/80.7.229.47/7733 // server three
```

I would like to be able to add multiple servers, here 1 to 10 or whatever, then display the correct server information, the protocol and ip and port. I have done that via split code, but I don't know how to do multiple servers.

I was thinking maybe a `for` loop to get the server number from `.ini` file:

```
sData := IniFile.ReadString('Data', 'Server['+ IntToStr(i) +']', '<none>');
```

Does anyone have any ideas how to do this?

Comment: You already provide the right answer. Not sure what your question is ? In any case, you may find [ReadSection](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Sydney/en/System.IniFiles.TIniFile.ReadSection) and [ReadSectionValues](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Sydney/en/System.IniFiles.TIniFile.ReadSectionValues) which builds a key=value list for you. This way, you can lookup from the variable list.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Drop the square brackets on the entry names:

```
[Data]
Server1=tcp/80.7.229.47/7799
Server2=udp/80.7.229.47/7780
Server3=tcp/80.7.229.47/7733
```

```pascal
sData := IniFile.ReadString('Data', 'Server' + IntToStr(i), '<none>');
```

To know how many servers are present, you could add a `ServerCount` entry, eg:

```
[Data]
ServerCount=3
Server1=tcp/80.7.229.47/7799
Server2=udp/80.7.229.47/7780
Server3=tcp/80.7.229.47/7733
```

```pascal
count := IniFile.ReadInteger('Data', 'ServerCount', 0);
for i := 1 to count do
begin
  sData := IniFile.ReadString('Data', 'Server' + IntToStr(i), '<none>');
  ...
end;
```

Or, you could use `IniFile.ReadSection()` to get all of the entry names into a local `TStringList`, then loop through that, eg:

```pascal
names := TStringList.Create;
try
  IniFile.ReadSection('Data', names);
  for i := 0 to names.Count-1 do
  begin
    if StartsText('Server', names[i]) then
    begin
      sData := IniFile.ReadString('Data', names[i], '<none>');
      ...
    end;
  end;
finally
  names.Free;
end;
```

Comment: Having that ServerCount entry can be a hassle. I usually read the full section and then parse all entries that match a given mask, e.g. Server??, allowing for numbers as well as other characters. It has the advantage that you don't need to keep those numbers in order. Just make sure they are unique. So your second example would be my way to go.

Comment: If the entries are named Server1 to Server3, you're not going to want to loop from 0 to Count-1.

Comment: @dummzeuch, unless you're talking about a performance issue, it doesn't matter if the numbers are in order or not.  Perhaps you mean without gaps?  That can also be handled by doing a ValueExists() check first, although that's probably best reserved for cases where you are changing and deleting entries but wanting to retain the numbers.

Comment: thanks for the help people, going to see if I can get this working today and I agree the 2nd option seams to be what I may need so ill test it and let you know.

Thanks